# Failed to execute goal on project temperature-thing: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ptcmanaged.thingworx:temperature-thing

Tags: xml, maven, jar, pom.xml, thingworx

when I run `mvn package` I get this error. any idea how this could be fixed?

```
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.4/junit-4.4.pom (2 KB at 4.0 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:28 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-26T21:57:51-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/222M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project temperature-thing: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ptcmanaged.thingworx:temperature-thing:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.thingworxs:thingworx-common:jar:5.0.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.thingworxs:thingworx-common:jar:5.0.0: Could not transfer artifact com.thingworxs:thingworx-common:pom:5.0.0 from/to ptc-managed-services-public (https://maker01.ptcmanaged.com/mvnrepo): Connect to maker01.ptcmanaged.com:443 [maker01.ptcmanaged.com/54.173.81.52] failed: Operation timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException


dyn-72-33-222-204:temperature-thing mona$ pwd
/Users/mona/iotlab/raspberry/temperature-thing
dyn-72-33-222-204:temperature-thing mona$ ls
README.md       bin             conf            pom.xml         src
dyn-72-33-222-204:temperature-thing mona$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the `pom.xml` file and delete this line by searching for `maker01` in the file:

```
<url>https://maker01.ptcmanaged.com/mvnrepo</url>
```

and add this line on the same place:

```
<url>http://maker01.cloud.thingworx.com/mvnrepo </url>
```

Comment: this link is dead now

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install the jar locally and modify the pom.xml file under the comment:
   
    
    
            Here, the new URL to the mvnrepo should be: http://maker01.clould.thingworx.com/mvnrepo i believe that the current URL is now http://maker01.ptcmanaged.com/mvnrepo

```
vi pom.xml 
  <!--<url>https://maker01.ptcmanaged.com/mvnrepo</url>-->
  <url>http://maker01.cloud.thingworx.com/mvnrepo </url>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this mean that you have fixed the tutorial and if I follow the tutorial I will get no error?

Comment: @MonaJalal, I believe if you feel that some extra info would be useful for readers of the question, go ahead and add an answer as a community wiki (rather than editing new information into the answer of someone else). This way you won't compete with Adrian's accepted answer (since you don't get rep for CW answers), while allowing other people to find the extra information if they come here.

Answer (score 0):

Failed to execute goal on project temperature-thing: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.ptcmanaged.thingworx:temperature-thing:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:

Failed to collect dependencies at com.thingworxs:thingworx-common:jar:5.0.0:

Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.thingworxs:thingworx-common:jar:5.0.0:

Could not transfer artifact com.thingworxs:thingworx-common:pom:5.0.0 from/to ptc-managed-services-public (https://maker01.ptcmanaged.com/mvnrepo):

Connect to maker01.ptcmanaged.com:443 [maker01.ptcmanaged.com/54.173.81.52] failed: Operation timed out -> [Help 1]